# Add the sum of two fields to a new field in the document

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to calculate sum of two fields, then create new field in document something like: 'totalSum'. But I dont know how to do this.
All in mongodb.
Here's an example:

```
    const obj = {
      name: 'John',
      foo: {
        fooA: 8753.19,
        fooB: 8753.19,
      },
      bar: {
        barA: 196.99,
        barB: 196.99,
      },
    };
    
    //Should be:
    const obj = {
      name: 'John',
      foo: {
        fooA: 8753.19,
        fooB: 8753.19,
        total: fooA+fooB
      },
      bar: {
        barA: 196.99,
        barB: 196.99,
        total: barA+barB
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/40DnYmMnEyU

Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields) to add new fileds total, compute values using [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    "foo.total": { $add: [ "$foo.fooA", "$foo.fooB" ] },
    "bar.total": { $add: [ "$bar.barA", "$bar.barB" ] }
  }
})
```

---

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "bar": {
      "barA": 196.99,
      "barB": 196.99,
      "total": 393.98
    },
    "foo": {
      "fooA": 8753.19,
      "fooB": 8753.19,
      "total": 17506.38
    },
    "name": "John"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank You!
I have one additional question, how to exclude "_id" from that object?

Comment: @Chazzy97 https://mongoplayground.net/p/ItiijQ1wRZ0 `"$project": {_id: 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

If it is mongodb specific, this might not address issue exactly, but is rather just a pure function to do the job.

I have written function named `calc` to solve your issues, you would pass in `obj` and it would return the output that you want.

Take note that is very specific to you input, so if you have different one please let me know.

function `calc`:

```
function calc(originalObj) {
    const obj = {...originalObj};
    for(const key in obj) {
        if(key !== 'name') {
            console.log(obj[key][`${key}A`], `${key}A`, obj)
            obj[key].totalSum = obj[key][`${key}A`] + obj[key][`${key}B`];
        }

    }
    return console.log(obj);

}
```